Error while creating javaDoc in Android studio. Error: No source files for package javadoc
When I try to create javadoc in android studio an error occurs:
Loading source file C:\Users\Letta\Desktop\CPPfile\LETI\PC_ForManager\app\src\test\java\com\example\pc_formanager\ExampleUnitTest.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\Letta\Desktop\CPPfile\LETI\PC_ForManager\app\src\main\java\com\example\pc_formanager\MainActivity.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\Letta\Desktop\CPPfile\LETI\PC_ForManager\app\src\androidTest\java\com\example\pc_formanager\ExampleInstrumentedTest.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\Letta\Desktop\CPPfile\LETI\PC_ForManager\app\src\main\java\com\example\pc_formanager\OtchetActivity.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\Letta\Desktop\CPPfile\LETI\PC_ForManager\app\src\main\java\com\example\pc_formanager\ErrorInEnter_Cifri.java...
Loading source file C:\Users\Letta\Desktop\CPPfile\LETI\PC_ForManager\app\src\main\java\com\example\pc_formanager\ErrorInEnter_Len.java...
Loading source files for package javadoc...
error: No source files for package javadoc
1 error

I don't know how and where to find these files. And how to specify and where to specify the path to them or insert a code snippet
Before this I had been struggling with UTF-8 symbols for a long time, and I solved it by adding the line javadoc -encoding utf-8 to the Command line arguments.
Javadoc settings
this is what the javaDoc generator settings look like.
code of file build.gradle.kts :
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.pc_formanager"
    compileSdk = 35

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.pc_formanager"
        minSdk = 31
        //noinspection EditedTargetSdkVersion
        targetSdk = 35
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.core.ktx)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)
}

